# Why is text utf-16 as opposed to utf-8

Tags: haskell, text

The `text` library [uses utf-16 internally](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.1.1.2/docs/Data-Text.html). utf-8 is a more commonly used encoding, especially in C libraries. In addition, utf-8 uses less memory most of the time. Why does `text` use utf-16?

Comment: TL;DR: in the 90s UCS-2 looked like a good idea since it was a fixed length encoding, too bad Unicode expanded, UCS-2 became UTF-16 and now we are stuck with the worst encoding ever in a lot of software.

Comment: Unicode 2.0, the version that introduced surrogate pairs, is from 1996, and according to https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-0.1, The first version of text has been released in 2009... this rules out the idea that text started as ucs-2... unless I'm wrong and the text library has prior history to the one on hackage (still, I've been using Haskell only after 2009, so I've no idea how things were back then)

Comment: `text` may have existed, but not yet hosted on Hackage.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There was a project to convert `text` to using utf8 internally, because that's irrelevant to the API it provides. After completing enough to benchmark, the project was considered not an improvement and not integrated with the mainline at this time. There is a chance it will be in the future, if it can become a sufficient improvement. Here's the full story: http://jaspervdj.be/posts/2011-08-19-text-utf8-the-aftermath.html